# Настройки IDLE Python

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы в IDLE Python ассоциированный блок начинался не с пустой строчки а с троеточия(...)?

Comment: А зачем вам код ломать?

Comment: Как раз наоборот, не ломать, а строить. Я хочу, чтобы было так :